# using State to get the input value while text is changing. if then, while text is chaing, all will rerender again. does this make the app very slow?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

while I am working on react app, I have very basic, but very important question.
as I am seeing the https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html, it is using State to get the input value like the following.

```
const App = () => {

    const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

    const handleText = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    };

    const list = [
        // 1000 items
    ]

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleText} />
            {list.map((item) => (
                <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

Here, I have a question.
whenever the user is typing on input control, text state will change. the everything will render again.

as you see my example code, the component is displaying the 1000 items.
this means ... whenever the user is typing on input control, the component is displaying the 1000 items, again.

if then, I think that this is very expensive.

current my solution is for fixing this issue. I am going to use React.memo like the following.

```
const ListItemMemo = React.memo(ListItem);

const App = () => {

    const [text, setText] = React.useState('');

    const handleText = (event) => {
        setText(event.target.value);
    };

    const list = [
        // 1000 items
    ]

    return (
        <>
            <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleText} />
            {list.map((item) => (
                <ListItemMemo key={item.id} item={item} />
            ))}
        </>
    );
};
```

on this status, I have 2 questions.

1. is my React.Memo solution the best?
2. is there any other way to get the input value when it is changing for high performance?

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple ways to handle this situation.

Currently, irrespective of whether `ListItem` component is wrapped in `React.memo` or not, `list.map(...)` will still execute every time `App` component re-renders.

Following demo shows the count of unnecessary executions of the `.map()` method.

```js
let listItemRenderCount = 0;
let mapCallbackExecutionCount = 0;

const list = new Array(1000).fill().map((_, idx) => {
  return { id: idx, name: "item name " + idx };
});

const ListItem = React.memo(({ item }) => {
  listItemRenderCount++;
  return <h3>{item.name}</h3>;
});

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const handleText = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("listItemRenderCount: " + listItemRenderCount);
    console.log("mapCallbackExecutionCount: " + mapCallbackExecutionCount);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleText} />
      {list.map((item) => {
        mapCallbackExecutionCount++;
        return <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Uncontrolled Component

One way to solve this problem is to make `input` an [uncontrolled component](https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html).
This will prevent a re-render whenever input `onChange` event is triggered.

You can use `useRef` hook to make the `input` component an uncontrolled component.

Following demo shows that if `input` is turned into an uncontrolled component, there are no unnecessary executions of the `.map()` method as well as there are no unnecessary re-renders of the `ListItem` components.

You don't even need `React.memo` for this.

```js
let listItemRenderCount = 0;
let mapCallbackExecutionCount = 0;

const list = new Array(1000).fill().map((_, idx) => {
  return { id: idx, name: "item name " + idx };
});

const ListItem = ({ item }) => {
  listItemRenderCount++;
  return <h3>{item.name}</h3>;
};

const App = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  const handleText = (event) => {
    console.log(inputRef.current.value);
  };
  
  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("listItemRenderCount: " + listItemRenderCount);
    console.log("mapCallbackExecutionCount: " + mapCallbackExecutionCount);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" ref={inputRef} onChange={handleText} />
      {list.map((item) => {
        mapCallbackExecutionCount++;
        return <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />;
      })}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Controlled Component

If you don't want to make `input` an uncontrolled component and still want to avoid unnecessary re-renders of `ListItem` component and also avoid the unnecessary execution of the callback function of the `.map()` method, then follow the following steps:

1. Create a `ItemList` component and move the `list.map(...)` in this newly created component
2. Wrap `ItemList` component in `React.memo` to prevent unnecessary re-renders of the `ItemList` component
3. Inside the `App` component, replace `list.map(...)` with `ItemList` component

Following demo shows the implementation of the above mentioned points:

```js
let listItemRenderCount = 0;
let mapCallbackExecutionCount = 0;

const list = new Array(1000).fill().map((_, idx) => {
  return { id: idx, name: "item name " + idx };
});

const ListItem = ({ item }) => {
  listItemRenderCount++;
  return <h3>{item.name}</h3>;
};

const ItemList = React.memo(({ itemList }) => {
  return itemList.map((item) => {
    mapCallbackExecutionCount++;
    return <ListItem key={item.id} item={item} />;
  });
});

const App = () => {
  const [text, setText] = React.useState("");

  const handleText = (event) => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  React.useEffect(() => {
    console.log("listItemRenderCount: " + listItemRenderCount);
    console.log("mapCallbackExecutionCount: " + mapCallbackExecutionCount);
  }, [text]);

  return (
    <div>
      <input type="text" value={text} onChange={handleText} />
      <ItemList itemList={list} />
    </div>
  );
};


ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.2/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.2/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You should wrap your `setText` to debounce function with some delay, it will be better for performance

```
  const handleText = event => {
    setText(event.target.value);
  };

  const debouncedChangeHandler = useCallback(
    debounce(handleText, 300)
  , []);
```

You can use debounce function from lodash library or write it yourself

usually it looks like this:

```js
function debounce(func, timeout = 300){
  let timer;
  return (...args) => {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    timer = setTimeout(() => { func.apply(this, args); }, timeout);
  };
}
```

Comment: this would cause a delay in the UI which is terrible UX

Comment: It's a very little delay and it doesn't lead to false emits

Comment: Hello thanks so much for your comment. but how about the using Rxjs https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/debounce? maybe will it helpful?

Answer (score 0):

use ref instead of state, this will prevent re-render. If u prefer state only, then debouncing is the solution. Please let me know if you need code.

Comment: yep please send me your working code. thanks!

Comment: //refer below

const UncontrolledComponent = () => {
  const inputRef = React.useRef();

  return (
    <div>
        <input ref={inputRef} />
 
    </div>
  );
};


// use inputRef.current.value to read the value of input

Comment: if it helps, please mark the answer useful. thanks!